# Cloning of rows and columns from a table and Colspan RowSpan

Tags: jquery, html-table, clone

I am using jQuery clone. The source table has the class `.donor` and it should be the base to make three tables: `#clone-head, #clone-cols, #clone-intersect.`

1. clone the first two lines [?rows?] of the original table (.donor) into Table #clone-head
2. clone the first two columns of the original table (.donor) into Table #clone-cols
3. clone the intersection of two tables (table #clone-head and table #clone-cols) into Table #clone-intersect

The problem stems from the fact that cloned cells are attributes colSpan and RowSpan;

```
<table class="donor" data-fix-rows="2" data-fix-cols="2">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">User</th>
        <th colspan="2">First</th>
        <th colspan="2">Second</th>
        <th colspan="2">Third</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>A1</th>
        <th>B1</th>
        <th>A2</th>
        <th>B2</th>
        <th>A3</th>
        <th>B3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>000</td>
        <td>Suzy</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>001</td>
        <td>Ashley</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>585 794,76</td>
        <td>711 436,05</td>
        <td>127 248,00</td>
        <td>1 289 982,81</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>002</td>
        <td>Simona</td>
        <td>489 826,30</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>591 025,64</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1 080 851,94</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>003</td>
        <td>Nicky</td>
        <td>263 111,43</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>304 993,43</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>568 104,86</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2">Total</td>
        <td>37 060 549,32</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>81 508 922,07</td>
        <td>585 794,76</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Total Cost</td>
        <td>37 060 549,32</td>
        <td>585 794,76</td>
        <td>44 455 620,75</td>
        <td>127 248,00</td>
        <td>81 508 922,07</td>
        <td>585 794,76</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="clone-head"></div><div id="clone-cols"></div><div id="clone-intersect"></div>
```

My Javascript code:

```
$.fn.getNonColSpanIndex = function() {
    if (!$(this).is('td') && !$(this).is('th')) {
        return -1;
    }

    var allCells = this.parent('tr').children();
    var normalIndex = allCells.index(this);
    var nonColSpanIndex = 0;

    allCells.each(function(i, item) {
        if (i == normalIndex)
            return false;

        var colspan = $(this).attr('colspan');
        colspan = colspan ? parseInt(colspan) : 1;
        nonColSpanIndex += colspan;
    });

    return nonColSpanIndex;
};


var $donor = $('.donor');
var fix_rows = $donor.data('fix-rows');
var fix_cols = $donor.data('fix-cols');

fix_rows--;
fix_cols--;

/* clone head -- */
var clone_header = $donor.find('tbody').clone();
clone_header.find('tr:gt(' + fix_rows + ')').remove();

$('#clone-head').html('<table class="t-header">' + clone_header.html() + '</table>');
/* -- clone head */



/* clone cols -- */
var clone_cols = $donor.find('tbody').clone();
var isRowSpan = 0;
clone_cols.find('tr').each(function(i, element) {
    $(element).find('th,td').each(function(index, el) {
        if (isRowSpan > 0) {
            $(el).remove();
        }
        if (el.rowSpan > 0) {
            isRowSpan = el.rowSpan;
        }
        if ($(el).getNonColSpanIndex() > fix_cols) {
            $(el).remove();
        }
    });

    if (isRowSpan > 0) {
        isRowSpan--;
    }
});

$('#clone-cols').html('<table class="t-cols">' + clone_cols.html() + '</table>');
/* -- clone cols */



/* clone intersect -- */
var clone_intersect = $('#clone-head').find('tbody').clone();
clone_intersect.find('th:gt(' + fix_rows + '),td:gt(' + fix_rows + ')').remove();

$('#clone-intersect').html('<table class="t-intersect">' + clone_intersect.html() + '</table>');
/* -- clone intersect */
```

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartini/qt0qvjLc/1/

Comment: Does my edit match your question? As far as i understood you only have troubles with the intersection - is this the case?

Comment: not quite, with #clone-cols also have a problem ...

Comment: If you shorten the table to only contain the rows and columns you need and only post the javascript you are having trouble with it is easier to help.

Comment: So, as I can see in the fiddle your first task is okey, and you are struggling in the second and third? And also, the third one is cloning the remaining table not cloned in 1) and 2) ?

Comment: yes, it is necessary

Comment: I forked your fiddle and changed it to this [table example](http://jsfiddle.net/oc652t4z/1/). What should be part of `#clone-cols`? I assume it should be all green cells: starting from `User, EmpId, EmpName` up to `TotalCost` - is this correct?
What should be part of `#clone-intersect`? I assume every cell without a background-color: so from `Foo to Fut` and from `6054` to `2724` and every cell inbetween?

Comment: I signed the cells in the table, are now seen in some of the cloned tables should get one or the other cell     http://jsfiddle.net/djmartini/gva0majj/

Answer (score 0):

I came with this solution. Pretty sure that there is a **way** better way to do it.

```
$.fn.getNonColSpanIndex = function()
{
    if(! $(this).is('td') && ! $(this).is('th'))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    var allCells = this.parent('tr').children();
    var normalIndex = allCells.index(this);
    var nonColSpanIndex = 0;

    allCells.each(function(i, item)
                  {
                      if(i == normalIndex)
                          return false;

                      var colspan = $(this).attr('colspan');
                      colspan = colspan ? parseInt(colspan) : 1;
                      nonColSpanIndex += colspan;
                  });

    return nonColSpanIndex;
};


var $donor = $('.donor');
var fix_rows = $donor.data('fix-rows');
var fix_cols = $donor.data('fix-cols');

fix_rows--;
fix_cols--;

/* clone head -- */
var clone_header = $donor.find('tbody').clone();
clone_header.find('tr:gt(' + fix_rows + ')').remove();

$('#clone-head').html('<table class="t-header">' + clone_header.html() + '</table>');
/* -- clone head */

/* clone cols -- */
var clone_cols = $donor.clone();

columnTh = clone_cols.find("th:contains('User')");
columnIndex_start = columnTh.getNonColSpanIndex();
columnIndex_end = columnIndex_start + parseInt(columnTh.attr("rowspan")) - 1; 

columnTh.addClass("keep");
clone_cols.find('tr td').filter(function(){
    var i = $(this).getNonColSpanIndex();
    return i >= columnIndex_start && i <= columnIndex_end;
}).addClass("keep");

clone_cols.find('tr').each(function(i, element)
{
    $(element).find('th,td').each(function (index, el)
    {
        if(!$(el).hasClass("keep"))
            $(el).remove();
    });
});
$('#clone-cols').html('<table class="t-cols">' + clone_cols.html() + '</table>');
/* -- clone cols */


/* clone intersect -- */
var clone_intersect = $donor.clone();

clone_intersect.find('tr td').filter(function(){
    var i = $(this).getNonColSpanIndex();
    return i > columnIndex_end;
}).addClass("keep");

clone_intersect.find('tr').each(function(i, element)
{
    $(element).find('th,td').each(function (index, el)
    {
        if(!$(el).hasClass("keep"))
            $(el).remove();
    });
});
$('#clone-intersect').html('<table class="t-intersect">' + clone_intersect.html() + '</table>');
/* -- clone intersect */
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt0qvjLc/3/).

Comment: The table #clone-cols is received correctly, but the table #clone-intersect has turned out not to be what you need. It should be crossing tables #clone-head, #clone-cols, and shall contain only cell «USERS»

Comment: I signed the cells in the table, are now seen in some of the cloned tables should get one or the other cell     http://jsfiddle.net/djmartini/gva0majj/